# Проблема с PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с таким: после установки PyCharm, не запускается код + постоянно выскакивает виндосовская консоль, в чем причина ? ОС: виндовс 7, но суть не винде, на работе все запускается без лагов, а дома нормально на работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из скрина ясно, что проблема в названии папки `"Файлы"`. Попробуйте переименовать ее английскими буквами, если заработает, копайте кодировки.

Comment: На скриншоте вижу пару странностей: прямые слэши в пути к скрипту в окошке (для windows характерны обратные слэши для пути)  и python.exe во временной директории. Я бы попробовл снести Python и PyCharm и установить заново.